# How to use function with parameters and check the parameters value "if condition" using JQuery

Tags: jquery

Below function was not working. please correct my mistake.

```
function setupScript() {
    OtherOnchanged('call_response', 'SPAN_Other', 'Other');
}

function OtherOnchanged (onChangedId, spanId, valueToCheck) {
    if ( $("#" + onChangedId).val() ==  valueToCheck) {
        alert ("Working");
    }
}
```

Comment: your javascript looks fine, the error must be somewhere else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fine, problem is probably somewhere else, in your HTML code.

Or ... are you calling setupScript() function  ?

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/8c7a0.php

```
<input id="call_response" value="Other"></div>
<script>
function setupScript() {
    OtherOnchanged('call_response', 'SPAN_Other', 'Other');
}

function OtherOnchanged (onChangedId, spanId, valueToCheck) {
    if ( $("#" + onChangedId).val() ==  valueToCheck) {
        alert ("Working");
    }
}
setupScript();
</script>
```

Comment: <label> Response:
<select name="call_response" id="call_response" onchange="javascript:OtherOnchanged('call_response','SPAN_Other','Other');">
    <option value="No Answer">No Answer</option>
    <option value="Not Available">Not Available</option>
    <option value="Not In Use">Not In Use</option>
    <option value="On MC, PL">On MC, PL</option>
    <option value="Pending Case">Pending Case</option>
    <option value="Other">Others - To specify</option>
</select>
</label>

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError:$is not defined

Comment: function setupScript() {
    OtherOnchanged('call_response', 'SPAN_Other', 'Other');
}

function OtherOnchanged (onChangedId, spanId, valueToCheck) {
//alert ("Working");
   if ( $("#" + onChangedId).val() ==  valueToCheck){
absent.js:9Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
  //      $("#spanId").show ();
        alert ("Working");//}
  //  else{
      //  $("#spanId").hide ();
    //  alert ("Not Working");
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

The only issue I see would be if you have no match for `$("#call_response")`.  For that to work, you need some DOM object with `id="call_response"` like this:

```
<div id="call_response"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Script works fine. Make sure:

- that jquery script included
- that element with id "call_response" is loaded when "setupScript()" function is executed
- that element with id "call_response" has value "Other" assigned
- that "setupScript()" function is actually executed

Do you get any javascript errors?